# Building Next.js 14 with AWS Amplify

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to deploy a Next.js 14 app with AWS Amplify and Amplify is failing to build the app giving the error:

`You are using Node.js 18.13.0. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.`

Is there any way I can upgrade the build image? Or downgrade the requirements?

If I try and edit the App settings in the Amplify Console I get an error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/gen2/start/quickstart/nextjs-app-router-server-components/#connect-branch-in-the-amplify-console):

> Under Advanced settings, navigate to Build image and enter amplify:al2023. The Amplify Amazon Linux 2023 build image supports Node.js versions 18 and 20 at build time. You can specify the Node.js version during your build through live package updates or nvm. Amplify Hosting will automatically deploy your compute runtime to match the Node.js version used at build time.

Comment: One thing to note is that the functionality above is not available in the "new Amplify experience". You have to use the old version for this to be available.

Comment: @Kong If you have an existing Gen-2 application, you can modify the build image by navigating to Hosting > Environment variables and creating a new environment variable _CUSTOM_IMAGE with the value amplify:al2023, then redeploying the build.